# Excel - copy row based on value in field

Tags: excel, vba

After data-analysis i have a table like mentioned below. But for databases purposes i would like to have per year a row. So in other words the values in column J represent the nr op copies per row.
Example, for row 3 i would like to have three rows where columns A-G are the same but column J represent year 2012 (row1) 2013 (row2) etc.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see how a pivot would help here. At best, a Pivot would summarize 2 rows into 1, wich is the exact contrary on what you are trying to achieve. You may want to give VBA a try.

There's a "quick and dirty" solution.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Resolve()

'Variables
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    'Source sheet
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet: Set wsSrc = wb.Sheets("Src")
    'Destination sheet
    Dim wsDst As Worksheet: Set wsDst = wb.Sheets("Dst")
    'Row counters
    Dim srcRow As Integer, dstRow As Integer
    'The actual data
    Dim lCompanyId As Long, sCEO1 As String, lDirectorId As Long
    Dim sCEO2 As String, lWorked As Long, lBegin As Long, lEnd As Long
    Dim iYearBeg As Integer, iYearEnd As Integer
    'Written data
    Dim lCurrentBeg As Long, lCurrentEnd As Long
    Dim iCurrentYear As Integer

'Here we go
srcRow = 2: dstRow = 2
Do Until wsSrc.Cells(srcRow, 1) = vbNullString
    'If the row already spans a single year : we just copy the row
    If wsSrc.Cells(srcRow, 8) = wsSrc.Cells(srcRow, 9) Then
        wsDst.Range("A" & dstRow & ":J" & dstRow) = wsSrc.Range("A" & srcRow & ":J" & srcRow)
        dstRow = dstRow + 1
    'Else, we start creating a new row for each year
    Else
        'We fetch the source line
        lCompanyId = wsSrc.Cells(srcRow, 1)
        sCEO1 = wsSrc.Cells(srcRow, 2)
        lDirectorId = wsSrc.Cells(srcRow, 3)
        sCEO2 = wsSrc.Cells(srcRow, 4)
        lWorked = wsSrc.Cells(srcRow, 5)
        lBegin = wsSrc.Cells(srcRow, 6)
        lEnd = wsSrc.Cells(srcRow, 7)
        iYearBeg = wsSrc.Cells(srcRow, 8)
        iYearEnd = wsSrc.Cells(srcRow, 9)
        'Now we create the new lines
        For iCurrentYear = iYearBeg To iYearEnd
            If iCurrentYear = iYearBeg Then
                lCurrentBeg = lBegin
                lCurrentEnd = (CLng(iCurrentYear) * 10000) + 1231
            ElseIf iCurrentYear = iYearEnd Then
                lCurrentBeg = (CLng(iCurrentYear) * 10000) + 101
                lCurrentEnd = lEnd
            Else
                lCurrentBeg = (CLng(iCurrentYear) * 10000) + 101
                lCurrentEnd = (CLng(iCurrentYear) * 10000) + 1231
            End If
            wsDst.Cells(dstRow, 1) = lCompanyId
            wsDst.Cells(dstRow, 2) = sCEO1
            wsDst.Cells(dstRow, 3) = lDirectorId
            wsDst.Cells(dstRow, 4) = sCEO2
            wsDst.Cells(dstRow, 5) = lWorked
            wsDst.Cells(dstRow, 6) = lCurrentBeg
            wsDst.Cells(dstRow, 7) = lCurrentEnd
            wsDst.Cells(dstRow, 8) = iCurrentYear
            wsDst.Cells(dstRow, 9) = iCurrentYear
            wsDst.Cells(dstRow, 10) = 1
            dstRow = dstRow + 1
        Next
    End If
    srcRow = srcRow + 1
Loop
```

End Sub

It's a simple loop reading every row in the source. If the row spans more than a year, one new row is created for each year. The code could easily be made more efficient (and resilient) by using classes and functions.

Comment: Thank you, but i get an error: the subscript is out of range....

Comment: No problem. Good luck !